# Problem importing .tex file into LyX -- ampersands displaying in IEEEeqnarray

Tags: lyx, ieeetran, import

I received a `.tex` file from a user and tried to open this up in Lyx 2.0.2 on Win.  After importing it into LyX, the document has ampersand characters everywhere in the equations as though LyX didn't parse the file correctly. I think this might be related to the `IEEEeqnarray` found throughout the document.  I can't seem to figure out how to get `IEEEeqnarray` portions of the document to render in LyX, rather than have the `IEEEeqnarray` portions display as TeX code in LyX.

When I produce the PDF in LyX, all the ampersands "&" can be seen in the PDF.

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, so I appreciate any advice.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043) I removed the thanks in your question. This is just the style here. Thanks is best expressed by up voting answers that help you.

Answer (score 4):

When you select `File`>`Import`>`LaTeX (plain)...` for a file `myfile.tex`, LyX executes

```
tex2lyx -f myfile.tex myfile.lyx
```

The `-f` flag forces overwriting of `myfile.lyx` if it already exists, but that's not important. According to the [`tex2lyx` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tex2lyx):

> The purpose of `tex2lyx` is to translate *well-behaved* LaTeX2e into
>   LyX. If your LaTeX file doesn't compile - or if you do weird things,
>   like redefining standard LaTeX commands - it may choke.

This is indeed what's happening here. Moreover, importing of files is *highly* dependent on so-called `.layout` files, which document how the import formatting occurs, and depends solely on the `\documentclass` given. If the `.layout` file is out-dated, or does not include all possible definitions, they are "lost in translation". Consider, by means of example, the following code for (say) `myfile.tex` (perhaps a very minimal version of what you received):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  a & = & b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j \nonumber\\
    && +\: k + l + m + n + o
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
Here is some more text.
\end{document}
```

Importing it into LyX shows

[image: Import .tex with \documentclass{IEEEtran} into LyX]

which is clearly wrong, and also produces the clearly incorrect output

[image: Incorrect output in LyX]

LyX was only able to correctly identify the *control sequences* since they are escaped with `\`, as well as the grouping braces `{`...`}` since they define macro/command arguments.

You have two options to correct this behaviour:

1. If the document is small enough, you need to manually copy the incorrectly imported code from the `.tex` source into a LyX ERT environment:

   [image: Manual insertion of ERT content in LyX]

   which then delivers the desired output<sup>*</sup>:

   [image: Correct output of ERT content in LyX]
2. Create a new or modify the existing layout associated with `IEEEtran`. Again, from the `tex2lyx` documentation:

   > By default, when `tex2lyx` sees a `\documentclass{foo}` command, it creates a file of textclass `foo` and reads the LyX layout file for that class (something like `/usr/local/share/lyx/layouts/foo.layout` OR `HOME/.lyx/layouts/foo.layout`).

   The specific file in question here would be `IEEEtran.layout`. To understand the contents of the `.layout` file, consider reading section **5 Installing New Document Classes, Layouts, and Templates** (under `Help`>`Customization`). Specifically, section **5.3 The layout file format** contains detailed information on this type of customizations.

---

<sup>*</sup> The additional vertical spacing (or skip) can be removed by "joining" the first paragraph with the `IEEEeqnarray` ERT, but the layout in LyX is horrible.